# Differential model of a fish population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have the folowing problem : 
The population dynamics of a certain fish can be modeled using the logistic equation
$   y′ = Ay − By^2 $. 
Furthermore, if it is allowed to fish 20% of the total fish population present at time; write
the differential equation including the harvesting term. Solve the resulting model taking $A = B = 1 $ and
$y(0) = 2$. 

I write the equation $y' = y - y^2 - \frac 15  y$ and find $y= \frac 54 + constant $ which doesn't make any sense since the population is supposed to change

I think my mistake is when I write the equation with the harvesting term but I can't figure what the equation is suppose to be.

Comment: For your differential equation  $ y' \ = \ \frac45 y - y^2 \ \ , $  your solution $ \ y \ = \ \frac45 \ $ happens to be one of the two equilibrium solutions of the equation.  We can write $  \  y' \ = \ \frac45 y - y^2 \ = \ y · (\frac45 - y ) \ \ , $ which gives $ \ y = 0 \ $ and $ \ y = \frac45 \ $ if we set $ \ y' = 0 \ \ . $  These are also called the "constant solutions"  or "trivial solutions" of the differential equation, since the implied rate of change for $ \ y \ $ is zero.  (I suspect there is a typo:  $ \ y = \frac54 \ $ would not give a zero value for $ \ y' \ . $ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: I will show you the solution for $y'=y-y^2$ in your case it is a similar procedure but with $y'=0.8y-y^2$.

Your differential equation is given as:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y-y^2 \implies \dfrac{dy}{y(1-y)}=dt$$
$$\text{partial fractions: }\implies \int \dfrac{dy}{y}+\int \dfrac{dy}{1-y} = \int dt$$
$$\implies \ln y-\ln(1-y)=t+\ln c_1.$$
$$\implies \ln\dfrac{y}{1-y}=t+\ln c_1.$$

Now use the initial condition $y(0)=2$:
$$\ln\dfrac{2}{1}=\ln c_1 \implies c_1 = 2.$$

Hence, we obtain

$$\ln\dfrac{y}{1-y}=t+\ln 2.$$

Now, exponentiate this expression and solve for y.

$$y=\dfrac{2\exp(t)}{1+2\exp(t)}=\dfrac{1+2\exp(t)-1}{1+2\exp(t)}=1-\dfrac{1}{1+2\exp(t)}$$

Comment: why is it ln(c1) and not just c1 ?

Comment: It does not matter what you choose. But often it is good to have $\ln c_1$ such that the constant does not appear as exponential after exponentiation.